# How to convert this type of "Dictionary" into a Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to send these results to a pandas dataframe. But first I want to know what it is. I mean, do I have 5 dictionaries? Is it a list of tuples inside each one?

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(reader, columns=reader.keys())
```

This is the error that I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Does `print(reader[0])` give you any output?

Comment: If it does, `reader[0].keys()` will give you your columns. This is an `OrderedDict` from the collections module. They were used a lot when Dictionaries didn't preserve their insertion order. Nowadays, they still have their uses but they aren't as prevalent.

Comment: Additionally, it looks like `ResultsReader` is an iterable of them. You shouldn't need to specify the columns in your dataframe if they all have the same structure, which it looks like they do.

Comment: @Axe319 It gives me the following error: ```ResultsReader object is not subscriptable

Comment: In that case, can you just do `df = pd.DataFrame(reader)`? If not you should be able to iterate over it and feed it into a list then convert the list to a dataframe.

Comment: Nothing appears. I guess I have to do the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
items = []
for item in reader:
   items.append(item)


import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(items)

df
```